# Is there a way to automate the configuration of Windows Settings (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to automate the configuration of all of the settings that are accessible by the panel below from Windows 10?

[image]

Comment: Yes. Copy the Registry settings.

Comment: That or use sysprep to make a customized image for install of windows 10

Comment: Your question is read as __please tell me how to change hundreds or thousands of different settings some specific to different computers__. Perhaps aim to your problem rather that everything.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are looking for is

> GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}

Right-click on your desktop and create a new **Folder**

Copy and paste the "God Mode" above in the folder name.

**Do Not Use Spaces In The Name**.


Press F5 to Refresh the Desktop.

Open the folder with a click or double-click and Explore will open showing you all the settings from the Control Panel *individually*.

Hope this helps, and is what you are searching for.